# Rails show form value only if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Hello i have a form like

```
    <%= form_for @user, 
    :url => url_for(:controller => 'frontend', 
    :action => 'registration_completion') do |f| %>


  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "Jméno", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And user is displaying the form where he can see already registered values, but some of that value i want to hide if some condition (specifically i need hide value of username if it contains @) It is possible? thank you

solution: it seems that

```
    <% if @user.name.include?('@') %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% else %>  
      <%= f.text_field :name, :value => "" %>
    <% end %>
```

works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest to put your logic inside a helper method:

```
module UserHelper
  def name_input(instance, f, options = {})
    options[:html_options] ||= {}

    f.text_field :name, options[:html_options] if instance.name.include?('@')
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= name_input(@user, f, html_options: { class: 'text_field' }) %>
```

If you want to simply hide the value you can do:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, value: @user.name.include?('@') ? @user.name : '' %>
```

Feel free to move this to a helper method also.

Comment: thank you, but i dont want hide a textbox, i dont view its value in that textbox, and it will be only in this form so what is benefit of using helper ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, I was just showing you that it is a good practice to put your view logic in a helper method.

Answer (score 1):

To create a hidden field when the username contains an `@` symbol you could use the following helper method

```
module UserHelper
  def hidden_name_field(user, f, options = {})
    options[:html_options] ||= {}

    if user.name.include?('@')
      f.hidden_field(:name, options[:html_options]) 
    else
      f.text_field(:name, options[:html_options])
    end
  end
end
```

and use it in you form:

```
<%= hidden_name_field(@user, f, html_options: { class: 'text_field' }) %>
```

Comment: thank you, but i dont want hide a textbox but only its value, how can i do that ?